# Configuring a WCF and StructureMap ServiceHostFactory from code

Tags: wcf, structuremap

I am creating a custom ServiceHost object and configuring it from code. My service is using InstanceContextMode.Single and ConcurrencyMode.Multiple and is hosted in a windows service.

As stated in a number of blogs/articles [(here)](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/), sharing a StructureMap container across instances requires using a custom InstanceProvider, ServiceBehavior and ServiceHostFactory.

My initialization code looks like this. I do not use a config file.

```
var baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"];
var port = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);

Host = new MyServiceHost(typeof(MediaFileServicePrivate), new Uri(string.Format(baseAddress, port)));

var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMediaFileServicePrivate), binding, string.Format(baseAddress, port));
```

How do I tell the service to use my custom service host factory? All the examples I can find configure it from the config file.

Is a ServiceHostFactory only used for IIS/WAS hosted scenarios? If so, how do I use SM for a self-hosted InstanceContextMode.Single service?

Answer (score 0):

Has this not been answered? essentially you tell it to use your servicefactory in the wcf markup

`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfWithDI.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"  Factory="WcfWithDI.MyServiceFactory"%>`

I have a sample project here all wired up with a custom provider (and structuremap)
https://github.com/billCreativeD/WCF_With_DI

Comment: In my case, there is no code behind. It's 100% C# as shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it makes little sense to say "the service uses the factory". You would use the Ninject factory to create your service:

```cs
var factory = new NinjectServiceHostFactory();

var address = new Uri(_baseAddress, path);
ServiceHostBase host = factory.CreateServiceHost(typeName, new[] {address});

var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TheType), binding, string.Format(baseAddress, port));
```

The directive in the .svc file is used to tell .NET how to instantiate your service.

Comment: The question is about how to configure StructureMap from code and not from a config file.

Comment: Yes."How do I tell the service to use my custom service host factory?" -- assuming "service host factory" refers to a WCF Service Host Factory, then the question is flawed. The service does NOT USE the factory. The factory CREATES the service.

Comment: Although you are right, ninject has no relevance. (Was a bit careless when writing, I think; I had the same problem as asked in your question, just using ninject instead of StructureMap.)